# What's wrong with this sources.list?

Tags: debian, apt

I always get the error:

```
W: Failed to fetch  http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/dists/stable-updates /Release  Expected entry »maindeb/source/Sources« couldn't be found in release file (wrong entry in sources.list or wrongly formed file).
```

(my translation from german, I don't know whether with english as system language you would get the exact same error)

This is my sources.list:

```
# standard
deb http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main 
deb-src http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main 

# security
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main 
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main 

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# deb http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main 
deb-src http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates maindeb 

deb http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/ experimental main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian sid main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the output says, you have a problem with maindeb:

`deb-src http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates` **maindeb**

Remove deb leaving only `main` and try again.